# Public action method 'Index' was not found on controller in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I m using log4net to log any exceptions. On the live website log file we are getting this error almost every min

`System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'Index' was not found on controller 'xxx.WebUI.Controllers.HomeController'`

The Index method is there in controller with the action filter  `[HttpGet]` and the post method has filters `[HttpPost] [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`. All is working fine in the browsers. Any ideas why it would be showing in logs?

The code for the controller looks like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductService _productsService;
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mappingEngine;
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public HomeController(IProductService _productsService, IMappingEngine mappingEngine, ILog logger)
    {
        _productsService= productsService;
        _mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("RouteToHomePageByRole", "Account");
        }

        return View(new RegisterInterestModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(RegisterInterestModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //some stuff
            }
        }
        catch (EntityValidationException ex)
        {
            // Validation errors
            foreach (var err in ex.ValidationErrors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(err.PropertyName, err.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            ViewBag.Error = true;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

And the full error is like below

> 2015-05-20 00:00:19,838 3290127 ERROR 5 WebUILogger:
>
> User:  System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method
> 'Index' was not found on controller
> 'xxxx.WebUI.Controllers.HomeController'.    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid<>.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid<>.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Try to remove [HttpGet] filter from the get method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that would fix it

Comment: Do you log the URLs that cause these errors?

Comment: Could you post your HomeController Index method? What kind of params and attributes does it have stamped on it? It may also have something to do with your routing defaults.

Comment: I had the same issue and it fixed it for me (I mean removing the [HttpGet]) Just try it for couple of days and see yourself.

Comment: @All I have added the controller code in question above

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I m not logging the URL's.

Comment: @stuartd I don't have HttpGet and HttpPost on the same action